# Setter Property in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

what is wrong?

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="ComboBoxStyleMex">
    <Setter Property="Name" Value="stcombo" />
</Style>
```

and

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItemBinding ="{Binding name_ru}" Header="Статус" CellStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyleMex}">
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

why name is not set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name can not be set in a Style.

A Name set from a Style applied to multiple instances in the same scope, like a Window, should in theory result in compiler errors due to duplicate names (remember Name turns into a code-behind accessible variable name) but Styles are not applied until runtime so the compiler wouldn't know about the Name from the Style, which it would need to use during compilation. To prevent this paradox, Styles can't set Name.

Comment: You can set x:Name directly on any element, but the key question is why you need the Name. What are you using it for once you get it set?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to do the Binding for SelectedValueBinding instead of SelectedItemBinding and try again

Hope this helps..